# Java Replacing Data In HTML File At Runtime

Tags: java, html

I have a HTML file that acts like a template. For example:

Dear Name Surname

is contained in a HTML file. At runtime I would like to replace this with Dear Someone Name. How is this possible in Java?

Having looked in Google I couldn't find anything. I know I can do this in XML, but in this scenario I have to use the above approach.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Comment: I am not asking for code. I am asking if it is possible in Java and what is the API called.

Comment: Yes, it's possible in Java.  Also,

Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Well I don't know where to start. I don't know what this concept is called.

Comment: I have only searched in Google words like template Java HTML. Nothing seems to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the degree of complexity of your file a simple [String.replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) or [String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) might do.

If you have more complex files I would recommend templating engines like [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/).